# Suppose the order of $g$ is even. What is the order of $g^2$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $n=2k$ be the order of $g$. Then $g^{2k}=1,$ for some natural $k$. Then, $$(g^2)^k=g^{2k}=1,$$ so the order of $g^2$ divides the order of $g$.

Similarly, let $m$ be the order of $g^2$. Then, $(g^2)^m=1$. *Then what?*

Any pointers in proceeding would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the order of $g$ is twice the order of $g^2$?

Comment: If $m<k$, then $2m<2k$ and $g^{2m}=e$, thus the order of $g$ is at most $2m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the order of $g^2$ is the smallest possible positive-integer value of $j$ such that $(g^2)^j = g^{2j} = 1$

We know setting $j=k$ satisfies this equation, so the order $m \leq k$. (In fact we can say $m|k$ -- we won't need that here, but think about why.)

On the other hand, if $m<k$, then $2m<2k$, and $g^{2m}=1$; what does this mean about the order of $g$, going back to the definition of order?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, there's a relation between the order of $g$ and the order of $g^i$:
$$\operatorname{order}(g^i)=\dfrac{\operatorname{order}(g)}{\gcd(\operatorname{order}(g),i)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Divide the powers of $g$ into even powers and odd powers:
$\langle g \rangle = \langle g^2 \rangle \cup g\langle g^2 \rangle $.

Since  $|\langle g^2 \rangle|= |g\langle g^2  \rangle|$, we get $|\langle g \rangle|= 2|\langle g^2  \rangle|$.