# Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. Prove or Disprove: If $o(g^2)=2$ then $o(g)=4$.

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$.

Prove or Disprove: If $o(g^2)=2$ then $o(g)=4$.

I tried to disprove it but without success, if it's a proof how can we prove it?

Comment: What is .. 'o'?

Comment: Hint : What is the smallest positive integer $k$ with $g^k=e$ ?

Comment: @Buraian Order of the element $g$

Comment: @Peter I try that: $(g^2)^2 = e$ then $g^4=e$ but it could be something smaller than $4$

Comment: check this page: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2775886/801734

Comment: @Questionmonkey I want to prove it without this formule

Comment: If the exponent is $1$ or $2$, can the order of $g^2$ then be $2$ ?

Comment: No, because $o(g^2)=2$ so that $g^2 \neq e$ and $o(g)$ can't be $1$ because $g\neq e$ so that prove that $o(g)=2$, is it right?

Comment: yes @Xavi you are right

Comment: You mean "proves that $o(g)=4$" , but apart from that you are right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose the order of $g$ is even. What is the order of $g^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2775880/suppose-the-order-of-g-is-even-what-is-the-order-of-g2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $g^4 = e$ so order of $g$ can only be $1,2,4$ now finish

Comment: Did you delete your acocunt, I remember it having more reputation

Comment: Please do not answer very low quality questions, like this one.

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), Aditya.

Comment: thanks @amWhy ..